# xskak : display mainline continuation from a loaded fen

Tags: xskak

I am using `xskak 1.7` package developped by *Ulrike Fischer*. It's a very clean way to write my book about chess.

My problem is I am always forced to show the beginning of the mainline of my game to use the xskak typo. And it's not the purpose of my writing. For example I would like to show directly the mainline from the move number 16 of my fen previously loaded and hide the first 15 ones to the reader :

"text... (no move showed to the reader)

```
\def\myfen{r1b2rk1/p3bpp1/1pn1p2p/q3P3/8/2PB1N2/PB2QPPP/R4RK1 w - - 0 16} 
\begin{center}
\chessboard[addfen=\myfen]
\end{center}
```

and white play `\mainline{16.Qd4...}` (showing the continuation to the reader, from fen move number 16) but it doesn't work (number wrong but i tried 16 16... 17 17.... nothing works).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make a complete example that can be used for tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the starting position with the chessboard keys, but you must set the moveid additionally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\def\myfen{r1b2rk1/p3bpp1/1pn1p2p/q3P3/8/2PB1N2/PB2QPPP/R4RK1 w - - 0 16} 
\newchessgame[setfen=\myfen,moveid=16w]
\chessboard

\mainline{16. Qe4}

\chessboard

\end{document}
```

[image]