# Using skak/chessboard for problems, not games

Tags: chessboard, skak

I want to use skak/chessboard to make the diagram of a problem. This accomplishes what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak,chessboard}

\begin{document}

\newgame
\def\myfen{8/R7/1R6/6k1/8/5K2 w}
\chessboard[setfen=\myfen]
            
\movecomment{1. Ra5 Kh4}
            
\newgame
\def\myfen{8/8/1R6/R7/7k/5K2 w}
\chessboard[setfen=\myfen]

\end{document}
```

But I would have preferred to use `\mainline`, instead of `\movecomment`, after the first diagram so that I don't have to type the new FEN position after every move. I understand that `\mainline` expects a new game (and that's why a get an error if I use it). Is there any other way to represent some position and its following moves when they're not part of a game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `xskak` package, not the `skak` package for more functionality. Then adapt Ulrike Fischer's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449887/xskak-display-mainline-continuation-from-a-loaded-fen) to your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,chessboard}

\begin{document}

\newgame
\def\myfen{8/R7/1R6/6k1/8/5K2 w}
\newchessgame[setfen=\myfen,moveid=16w]
\chessboard

\mainline{16. Ra5+ Kh4} 

\chessboard        
\end{document}
```

The result running in Gummi is:
[image]

The documentation for `xskak`, which is an extension of the `skak` package can be found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak) on CTAN.

Comment: Thank you, this works very well (I had not seen Fischer's answer). The only thing I'd say is that I need to assume some arbitrary move number. Since this is a problem, not part of a game, I think I could simply change your 16 for 1, and let (in my example) Ra5+ be move 1.

Comment: Correct. Change to `moveid=1w` and then start in mainline with 1.